# ${variable} doesnt get replaced when html template is read as a string from a file in node app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, html-templates

I am using .setContent() method of puppeteer to set the content of a page.
I am reading a png image as:

```
var image = fs.readFileSync('some_image.png'); // image is a buffer object
```

The below code works as image template variable is replaced by its value in htmlstring string:

main.js

```
var image = fs.readFileSync('some_image.png');
const htmlString = `
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${image.toString('base64')}" width=960 height=750></div>
</body>
</html>`;
await page.setContent(htmlString);
```

Now I dont want to declare htmlString variable in my main.js instead want to keep that in a separate file and somehow use that in my main.js

For this I tried

creating a pages.html file with the html content as below

pages.html

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${image.toString('base64')}" width=960 height=750></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in my main.js

```
var image = fs.readFileSync('some_image.png');
var htmlfromfile = fs.readFileSync('pages.html').toString();
```

this does not work and my img tag still has "data:image/png;base64,${image.toString('base64')}" and not the buffer value of image in it. How do i get this working ?

Comment: Template strings must be quoted with back-quote characters, not double-quotes (` and not ").

Comment: Why would it replace anything? `fs.readFileSync` is for reading in files as byte data. You're not getting a string back, you get a `Buffer` object. So you don't see things getting replaced for two reasons: 1) it's not a string, and 2) `fs` is not a templating engine, it is the file system API. If you want to use HTML templates, use a templating engine.